# Query page templates on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme in Wordpress which use a code to show products of Woocommerce. However, I want to use the same function for showing also pages with a certain template. Here is what I have done until now:

```
<div>
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                     'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                     'value' => 'room-template.php'
                )
            )
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

            <div>
                <div>                       
                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail(); }?>
                    <div>
                        <div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Buy Now</a></div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found');
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

Whereas, I have 2 pages with this template, the result is "No products found". P.S. The divs are there because I use them for CSS classes. I've just removed the classed to make it easier to read.

Here is the output of the WP_Query:

```
WP_Query Object ( [query] => Array ( [post_type] => page [post_status] => publish [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => _wp_page_template [value] => room-template.php )))[query_vars] => Array ( [post_type] => page [post_status] => publish [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => _wp_page_template [value] => room-template.php ))[error] => [m] => [p] => 0 [post_parent] => [subpost] => [subpost_id] => [attachment] => [attachment_id] => 0 [name] => [static] => [pagename] => [page_id] => 0 [second] => [minute] => [hour] => [day] => 0 [monthnum] => 0 [year] => 0 [w] => 0 [category_name] => [tag] => [cat] => [tag_id] => [author] => [author_name] => [feed] => [tb] => [paged] => 0 [comments_popup] => [meta_key] => [meta_value] => [preview] => [s] => [sentence] => [fields] => [menu_order] => [category__in] => Array ( )[category__not_in] => Array ( )[category__and] => Array ( )[post__in] => Array ( )[post__not_in] => Array ( )[tag__in] => Array ( )[tag__not_in] => Array ( )[tag__and] => Array ( )[tag_slug__in] => Array ( )[tag_slug__and] => Array ( )[post_parent__in] => Array ( )[post_parent__not_in] => Array ( )[author__in] => Array ( )[author__not_in] => Array ( )[suppress_filters] => [ignore_sticky_posts] => [cache_results] => 1 [update_post_term_cache] => 1 [update_post_meta_cache] => 1 [posts_per_page] => 10 [nopaging] => [comments_per_page] => 50 [no_found_rows] => [order] => DESC )[tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object ( [queries] => Array ( )[relation] => AND )[meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object ( [queries] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => _wp_page_template [value] => room-template.php ))[relation] => AND )[date_query] => [request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS exitn_posts.ID FROM exitn_posts INNER JOIN exitn_postmeta ON (exitn_posts.ID = exitn_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND exitn_posts.post_type = 'page' AND ((exitn_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND ( (exitn_postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_page_template' AND CAST(exitn_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'room-template.php') ) GROUP BY exitn_posts.ID ORDER BY exitn_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10 [posts] => Array ( )[post_count] => 0 [current_post] => -1 [in_the_loop] => [comment_count] => 0 [current_comment] => -1 [found_posts] => 0 [max_num_pages] => 0 [max_num_comment_pages] => 0 [is_single] => [is_preview] => [is_page] => [is_archive] => [is_date] => [is_year] => [is_month] => [is_day] => [is_time] => [is_author] => [is_category] => [is_tag] => [is_tax] => [is_search] => [is_feed] => [is_comment_feed] => [is_trackback] => [is_home] => 1 [is_404] => [is_comments_popup] => [is_paged] => [is_admin] => [is_attachment] => [is_singular] => [is_robots] => [is_posts_page] => [is_post_type_archive] => [query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => 436de9012210c4e9c717fd5edf527108 [query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 1 [thumbnails_cached] => [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `get_template_part` to print a specific template.

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

If you want to use a specific `function()` within a template file then you might want to move this function to a common function library or your `functions.php` file.

-- EDIT --

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS exitn_posts.ID 
FROM exitn_posts INNER JOIN exitn_postmeta ON (exitn_posts.ID = exitn_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND exitn_posts.post_type = 'page' 
AND ((exitn_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
AND ( (exitn_postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_page_template' AND CAST(exitn_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'room-template.php') ) 
GROUP BY exitn_posts.ID ORDER BY exitn_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

If executing this on the Database doesn't bring up the data it means either it doesn't exist or something within is missing. Its hard to tell this from my hand. I have pretty much the same pattern in one of my personal query and its Data is returned without any issues.

Example :

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => explode( ',', $post_type ),
     'tag' => $tag,
     'p' => $id,
     'category_name' => $category,
     'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
     'order' => $order,
     'orderby' => 'meta_value',
     'meta_key' => '_my_named_key',
     'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => '_my_named_key'
        )
     ),
     'no_found_rows' => 1
);
```

-- Working Edit --

Make sure the value is a existing in the Database by looking it via something like phpMyAdmin or making a SQL Query onto it. This case was solved in chat full value had an unknown prefix `page-templates/`.

Comment: Well, the above is a code to query and show all the pages with a certain template. However, something on the query goes wrong, since it returns "No products found". And I cannot see the reason

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris if you do $loop->request; and copy/paste the SQL and execute it seperatly on the database can you see something odd?

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris Also maybe placing `meta_key => '_wp_page_template'` before the `meta_query` statement might solve the issue here.

Comment: Didn't help. Unfortunately :(

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris Does the meta_key actually exist in your Database? Can you also paste the SQL Generated by WP_Query?

Comment: Update the question with the output of the WP_Query

Comment: It doesn't return "empty" in SQL...So, I guess I should investigate it more :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76651/discussion-between-anastasios-ventouris-and-musk).